# What is this light sensor part?

Tags: sensor, light

This light sensor off of my lincoln town car stopped working.  It is supposed to turn on/off my headlights when it is bright enough outside.  I don't know what this part would be and would love some help finding a replacement.[image: Top of sensor PCB]  [image: Back of PCB]

Comment: How did you determine that it's this sensor which is broken and not something else like a wiring issue?

Comment: @brhans, this is part of my troubleshooting.  The LED on the PCB still works.  Other lincoln town car forums say that this is the issue to get this replaced, but it is impossible to find the OEM assembly anymore.  I'm hoping that a component level replacement will be available.

Comment: Please crop your images so there's not so much wasted space.

Comment: It might be as simple as two cadmium or silicon light sensors. Maybe they would have markings on the bottom surface. From your picture there looks to be some foreign material or corrosion between the pins, looks like something yellow or white there. If so be sure to clean that up.  The parts also seem to be gold plated, that makes me think of old Hp components.

Comment: That little board was almost certainly custom-made for the manufacturer.  Can you find a donor from a junkyard?

Comment: @rdtsc I've tried getting a donor from the junkyard.  No luck there for me in my area.

Comment: three pin device with a small photosensitive area, kinda looks like this (obsolete) honeywell sensor: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/honeywell-sensing-and-productivity-solutions/SDP8371-001/2513171 - infrared with digital output. I think your best bet is to measure the voltages on that board when installed and lit/dark, and possibly reverse engineer the body control module (or whatever) that it's connected to. Once you know HOW the system works making your own custom replacement from extant sensors will be simple enough.

Comment: Is there any chance that there is a component on the back side of the PCB that over heated and caused the apparent discoloration between the sensor pins marked G and Sd ?

Answer (score 1):

This may actually be a combination ambient light and oncoming headlight sensor. Seems the LED doesn't have a limiting resistor, (though you didn't show the bottom of the PCB). A single LED like this can be used as a simple light sensor. Was there anything lighting up or blinking when this part was working correctly?

The other pair of sensors may be forward facing to detect oncoming headlights, (they might control your headlight high/low beam setting). With 3-pins these parts could be a pair of photo transistors in some arrangement.

The circuit looks very simple, so if you draw out the circuit you may get a better idea of how it works and maybe a way to test, recreate, substitute, or repair it.

Often before automotive electronic parts go bad the physical connections, wiring, solder joints, or some mechanical part wears out due to fatigue and/or vibration. In this case perhaps even some liquid contamination (if those yellow and whites patches are actually something between the pins). You might also follow the wiring back to the ECU to be sure the signals are getting through.

.

**EDIT:**

Here is a [Youtube video of someone replacing an automatic headlight sensor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CmvX3qBj30) on a Lincoln town car, and sure enough at the start of the video the thing has a red blinking light.

Here is an [automatic headlight sensor from Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1990-02-Ford-Lincoln-Mercury-New-Ford-Genuine-Dashboard-Sun-Light-Sensor-M1168-/261776650912?_ul=IL) that may be close to what you need. Does this look similar to the assembly that you pulled the PCB out of?  I noticed that as on your part this assembly also has a 6 pin interface. There are a number of other similar parts on Ebay (new and used).

Finally here is a [Napa automatic headlight sensor](https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/TEEAHS500?cid=paidsearch_shopping_dcoe_google&campaign=GSC-Fasteners-Hardware&campaign_id=10947735022&adgroup_id=107081865346&adtype=pla&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3L39wJHR_wIVR-_ICh22jggeEAkYAyABEgLX4PD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&) that also has 6 pins.

Searching with "Automatic Headlight Sensor" along with your car's year, make, model, and trim, you may be able to find an after market part that is close enough to what you need.

.

Comment: The LED does have a resistor on the bottom.  The LED works when it's plugged into the circuit.  It mostly just blinks when the car is locked.  The high/low beam isn't controlled by this, that's a manual control.  This car isn't that fancy.  It's a straight forward circuit, but there are 4 traces that go to the bottom of the daughter board and they are labeled Sp, T, Sd, and G. There's a cap inseries with the T pin on the bottom of the main board.  Then there are 3 SMD components on the bottom of the daughter board.  I can't tell if those are resistors or caps. There is a label that says 090-M.

Comment: Any idea what that might mean?

Comment: @2ndpower - That does complicate things considerably.  An additional picture of the PCB bottom would have helped. So the assembly may be a theft deterrent indicator and an ambient light sensor.  As in my text above you might trace out the circuit then re-post a schematic diagram, that may generate some additional ideas and comments.  No guesses on the text markings for now, (except for maybe G = Ground).